# Setting HostName to 127.0.0.0

Tags: php

I am using Megento 2.1.8 and Php version php 7.0.20 on Mac with MAMP I am getting error when re-indexing:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. people resolved issue by setting the database hostname as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost .

Question is: how can I set the database hostname as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback ip address, not the host name. From php you can connect to a mysql server located on the localhost by specifying 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as the host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to phpmyadmin->opendatabase->open coreconfigdata -> change securebaseurl and insecure base url->use instead of localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the file `/app/etc/env.php` under your magento installation directory, you can change the database host there